# Поместить данные на лист GoogleSheet через клиент

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Привет, всем.
Есть *GoogleSheet (output)*, на который из-под клиента нужно проставить число 15. Я составил программу но она просто ничего не делает. Программ состоит из: `Code.gs` (код на стороне сервера), `Client.js.html` (код на стороне клиента), `Main.js.html` (работает после загрузки документа), `Index.html`(точка входа). В чем может быть ошибка? подскажите пожалуйста.

### Code.gs

```
function onOpen(e) {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
    .createMenu('Value')
    .addItem('Estimate', 'tryExchange')
    .addToUi();
}

function putValuesRange(value) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var outputSheet = ss.getSheetByName('output');
  return outputSheet.getRange(5, 5).setValue(value);
}

function tryExchange() {
  HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index.html')
    .evaluate();
}
```

### Client.js.html

```
<script>
  var Client = (function(client) {
    client.putData = function(v) {
      google.script.run
        .putValuesRange(v);

    };
    return client;
  })(Client || {});
</script>
```

### Main.js.html

```
<script>
  window.onload = function() {
    Client.putData(15);
  }
</script>
```

### Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <base target="_top">
</head>

<body>
  <?!=HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Client.js').getContent();?>
    <?!=HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Main.js').getContent();?>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Нет необходимости создавать обертки `<html></html>`, достаточно `<script></script>`. Поправил. Ждем экспертной правки.

Comment: @AlexanderIvanov, код вопроса править не то чтобы принято. Обычно если какие-то стилистические замечания их так в комментариях и оставляют, или в ответ добавляют

Comment: @Утка, как много пользователей читает дальше первого ответа? Предлагаете создавать еще одно заблуждение на ровном месте? И так тема дохлая. Пусть хоть порядок будет и красота. В любом случае, до меня дошло, я учту, спасибо за замечание.

Comment: @AlexanderIvanov, ну так вы первый ответ можете поправить, благо он ваш =)  Сам вопрос обычно править не принято, чтобы привести код автора в первозданном виде, на всякий случай

Comment: @AlexanderIvanov, код в вопросе имеет смысл править лишь для того чтобы привести его к виду удобному для восприятия другими пользователями. То есть, **поправить форматирование текста кода, не более**. Иначе может случиться так, что в результате правок перестанет быть понятна суть вопроса.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Концептуально, вы подошли очень правильно. Как мне кажется, это хороший код.

А вот практически, не понятно, что возвращает `tryExchange`?

```
function tryExchange() { //void

  var userInterface = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index.html')
    .evaluate();

  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(userInterface, 'Estimate');

}
```

Бонус. [HtmlService. Как передать данные клиенту?](https://gist.github.com/oshliaer/fd0ffc5436bf49b1d831)

Comment: Как я понимаю tryExchange просто создает темплейт из Index.html, т.е. запускает программу. Затем вызывается Main.js, которая в свою очередь вызывает Client.js. Client.js через google.script.run должен вызывать серверную функцию putValuesRange, которая и вернет значение на GoogleSheet.

Comment: [The function that opens the user interface must pass your HTML file as an HtmlOutput object to the showModalDialog() or showSidebar() methods of the Ui object for the active document, form, or spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/#serve_html_as_a_google_docs_sheets_or_forms_user_interface).

Comment: Таким образом ваш код ничего не должен возвращать (`void`), но должен передать в [Ui](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui) набор [HtmlOutput](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-output).

Comment: @АндрейКуравлев, ачивку бы, или что-то не так с решением?

Comment: Какую ачивку? Я недавно на ресурсе.

Comment: Отметьте ответ как решение.